# Scrapy yielding item after multiple callbacks

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, data-extraction

I'm new to scrapy and having issues with it. I don't think I have completely grasped how to write code in an aynchronous way.

Here is what the code is trying to achieve:

1. Visit a state park url and grab all the individual park urls. Create
   a scrapy item (or any way to store data) with each individual park
   as a single item to be yielded.
2. Visit each park url and scrape the content of the park based on keyword matching (append data function). Add data to scrapy item for that park.
3. Find links in that park that match certain keywords (matching links function). Visit that link and again scrape based on keyowrds. Add data to scrapy item for that park.
4. Yield that scrapy item and move onto the next park.

Here are the problems:

1. I have set up the scrapy item incorrectly and despite visiting all links, I get the same information duplicated across all the rows.
2. I would like to yield only after visiting all the links in the park page and appending that data the respective park. I want to yield the information only once for each park. (However, I am open to different approaches that may require post-processing of the results). I plan to have each park as a row of the dataframe.

I have used beautifulsoup because the tag syntax is more natural. I don't think that is the problem, but I might be wrong.

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks.

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)

def generate_item(fields):
    item = Item()
    for f in fields:
        item.fields[f] = Field()
        item[f] = []
    return item

Parkdata = generate_item(cols_data.index)

class parkcrawler(sc.Spider):
    
    name = 'parkcrawler'

    def __init__(self):
        self.park_cols = {k:[] for k in cols_data.index}
        self.base_url = 'https://www.alapark.com'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.alapark.com/parks'
        yield sc.Request(url, callback = self.parse)

    def parse(self, r):
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

        for s1 in tqdm(soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4')[:2]):
            try:
                for div in s1.findAll(class_ = 'field-content parks-list-title'):
                    #self.name = div.find(href=True).text
                    Parkdata['Park Image or Video'] = self.base_url + s1.find('img', src = True)['src']
                    Parkdata['Protected Area/Park Name'] = div.find(href=True).text
                    Parkdata['Website'] = self.base_url + div.find(href=True)['href']
                    
                    yield r.follow(div.find(href=True)['href'], callback = self.ppagecontent, dont_filter = True, meta = {'item': Parkdata})
                    yield r.follow(div.find(href=True)['href'], callback = self.pparklinkcontent, dont_filter = True, meta = {'item': Parkdata})
            except AttributeError:
                print(div)


    def ppagecontent(self, r):
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
        Parkdata = r.meta['item']

        aside = soup.find('aside')
        content = soup.find(class_ = 'columns')

        phone = aside.find('h4', text = re.compile("phone", re.IGNORECASE))
        for item in phone.find_next_siblings():
            if item.name == 'h4':
                break
            Parkdata['Telephone Number - Information'].append(item.text)

        hours = aside.find('h4', text = re.compile("hours", re.IGNORECASE))
        for item in hours.find_next_siblings():
            if item.name == 'h4':
                break
            Parkdata['Hours of Operation Detail'].append(item.text)

        for c in content.findAll('p'):
            append_data(c.text, Parkdata, 'searchcontent')
            Parkdata['Description'].append(c.text)

        for l in content.findAll(href = True):
            if not l['href'].startswith('http'):
                append_data(self.base_url + l['href'], Parkdata, 'searchlink')
            else:
                append_data(l['href'], Parkdata, 'searchlink')

        for img in content.findAll('img', src = True):
            if not img['src'].startswith('http'):
                append_data(self.base_url + img['src'], Parkdata, 'searchlink')
            else:
                append_data(img['src'], Parkdata, 'searchlink')
                
        yield Parkdata

    def pparklinkcontent(self, r):
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
        Parkdata = r.meta['item']

        content = soup.find('div', class_ = "column is-4 content-sidebar")
        all_links = [link['href'] for link in content.findAll(href = True) if link['href'].startswith('/parks/')]

        matching_links = [get_matching_links(link, Parkdata) for link in all_links]
        for i,d in enumerate(matching_links):
            if d != {}:
                link = list(d.keys())[0]
                cols = list(d.values())[0]
                yield r.follow(link, callback = self.plinkpagecontent, meta= {'cols': cols, 'item': Parkdata})
        

    def plinkpagecontent(self, r):
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
        cols = r.meta['cols']
        Parkdata = r.meta['item']
        
        content = soup.find(class_ = re.compile('main-content'))

        for c in content.findAll('p'):
            for col in cols:
                Parkdata[col].append(c.text)
            append_data(c.text, Parkdata, 'searchcontent')

        for l in content.findAll(href = True):
            if not l['href'].startswith('http'):
                append_data(self.base_url + l['href'], Parkdata, 'searchlink')
            else:
                append_data(l['href'], Parkdata, 'searchlink')

        for img in content.findAll('img', src = True):
            if not img['src'].startswith('http'):
                append_data(self.base_url + img['src'], Parkdata, 'searchlink')
            else:
                append_data(img['src'], Parkdata, 'searchlink')
        
        yield Parkdata
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the Scrapy item has to be declared each time in the loop. Would love to have some clarification on this. Also placing the yield outside of the for loop worked for me. So the first for loop looks like this:

```
    def parse(self, r):
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

        for s1 in tqdm(soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4')[:2]):
            try:
                for div in s1.findAll(class_ = 'field-content parks-list-title'):
                    Parkdata = generate_item(cols_data.index)

                    Parkdata['Park Image or Video'] = self.base_url + s1.find('img', src = True)['src']
                    Parkdata['Protected Area/Park Name'] = div.find(href=True).text
                    Parkdata['Website'] = self.base_url + div.find(href=True)['href']
                    
                    yield r.follow(div.find(href=True)['href'], callback = self.ppagecontent, dont_filter = True, meta = {'item': Parkdata})
                    yield r.follow(div.find(href=True)['href'], callback = self.pparklinkcontent, dont_filter = True, meta = {'item': Parkdata})
            except AttributeError:
                print(div)
            yield Parkdata
```